# How to set a different stylesheet for contained widgets than that of the the container

Tags: c++, qt, qtstylesheets

I have a section that is a top widget, the color of the top widget is gray, and I've put several widgets inside the top widget, QComboBox, QLineEdit and 2 QButton.

But when I right click on QLineEdit, the color of default context of window is gray, or when I open the QComboBox the color of background is gray.

I've set the background color of these two widgets to white but it doesn't work.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The style sheet propagates to all the child widgets, so you have to limit their range by using the right selectors. Since the context menu is a child of the QLineEdit it is also affected.

```
// What you have probably done:
myLineEdit->setStyleSheet("background-color: gray");

// What you should have done:
myLineEdit->setStyleSheet("QLineEdit { background-color: gray }");      

// What you should do if there might be child widgets of the same type 
// but for which you don't want the style to apply:
myLineEdit->setObjectName("myLineEdit");
myLineEdit->setStyleSheet("QLineEdit#myLineEdit { background-color: gray }");
```

See [The Style Sheet Syntax - Selector Types](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/stylesheet-syntax.html#selector-types) for details.